# Combinatorial proof of fibonacci

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, combinatorial-proofs

I need to proof this expression combinatorially
$f_{2n+1}= \sum_{i \geq 0} \sum_{j\geq 0} \binom{n-i}{j} \binom{n-j}{i}$ for all $n \geq 0$. As $f_1 = 1, f_2=2$

I dont know how to start combinatorial argument to this problem .I tried to use induction but it's hard to get the inductive result

Comment: Is induction allowed ? (The Fibonacci numbers are defined by recurrence, not combinatorially.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust, one could of course take a combinatorial problem for which the Fibonaccis are the answer as the basis for a combinatorial solution. (E.g. the number of ways to tile a $2\times n$ rectangle with $1\times 2$ or $2\times 1$ tiles.)

Comment: Sure @Yves Daoust

Comment: @Cheerful Parsnip Could you hep me sir? :(

Comment: @SutMar, I don't see a good combinatorial proof but I think it's an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

What  follows is  not a  double  counting proof.  It nonetheless  uses
combinatorial methods to arrive at the answer.

Observe that the generating function of the Fibonacci numbers is

$$\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}.$$

so that we have $F_0 = 0$ and $F_1 = F_2 = 1.$

We seek to evaluate

$$\sum_{p=0}^n \sum_{q=0}^n {n-p\choose q} {n-q\choose p}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n \sum_{q=0}^n 
{n-p\choose n-p-q} {n-q\choose n-p-q}.$$

Note that  on the first line the binomial coefficient ${n\choose  k} =
n^{\underline{k}}/{k!}$ starts producing non-zero values when $p\gt n$
and $q\gt n.$ This is not desired here, hence the upper limits. On the
second line we  use the convention that ${n\choose k}  = 0$ when $k\lt
0,$ which is  also the behavior when residues are  used. Continuing we
find

$$\sum_{p=0}^n \sum_{q=0}^n 
[z^{n-p-q}] (1+z)^{n-p} [w^{n-p-q}] (1+w)^{n-q}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n [w^n] (1+w)^n \sum_{p=0}^n \sum_{q=0}^n 
z^{p+q} (1+z)^{-p} w^{p+q}  (1+w)^{-q}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n [w^n] (1+w)^n 
\sum_{p=0}^n z^p w^p (1+z)^{-p} \sum_{q=0}^n 
z^q w^q (1+w)^{-q}.$$

Here the coefficient extractor controls the range and we may
continue with

$$[z^n] (1+z)^n [w^n] (1+w)^n 
\sum_{p\ge 0} z^p w^p (1+z)^{-p} 
\sum_{q\ge 0} z^q w^q (1+w)^{-q}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n [w^n] (1+w)^n 
\frac{1}{1-zw/(1+z)} \frac{1}{1-zw/(1+w)}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{n+1} [w^n] (1+w)^{n+1} 
\frac{1}{1+z-zw} \frac{1}{1+w-zw}.$$

Now we have

$$\frac{1}{1+z-zw} \frac{1}{1+w-zw}
\\ = \frac{1-w}{1+z-wz} \frac{1}{1+w-w^2}
+ \frac{w}{1+w-wz} \frac{1}{1+w-w^2}.$$

We get from the first piece treating $z$ first

$$[z^n] (1+z)^{n+1} \frac{1-w}{1+z-wz}
= [z^n] (1+z)^{n+1} \frac{1-w}{1-z(w-1)}
\\ = (1-w) \sum_{p=0}^n {n+1\choose n-p} (w-1)^p
= - \sum_{p=0}^n {n+1\choose p+1} (w-1)^{p+1}
\\ = 1 - \sum_{p=-1}^n {n+1\choose p+1} (w-1)^{p+1} 
= 1 - w^{n+1}.$$

The contribution is

$$[w^n] (1+w)^{n+1} \frac{1-w^{n+1}}{1+w-w^2}
= [w^n] (1+w)^{n+1} \frac{1}{1+w-w^2}.$$

The second piece yields

$$[z^n] (1+z)^{n+1} \frac{w}{1+w-wz} 
= \frac{1}{1+w} [z^n] (1+z)^{n+1} \frac{w}{1-wz/(1+w)}
\\ = \frac{w}{1+w} 
\sum_{p=0}^n {n+1\choose n-p} \frac{w^p}{(1+w)^p}
= \sum_{p=0}^n {n+1\choose p+1} \frac{w^{p+1}}{(1+w)^{p+1}}
\\ = -1 + 
\sum_{p=-1}^n {n+1\choose p+1} \frac{w^{p+1}}{(1+w)^{p+1}}
= -1 + \left(1+\frac{w}{1+w}\right)^{n+1}
\\ = -1 + \frac{(1+2w)^{n+1}}{(1+w)^{n+1}}.$$

The contribution is

$$[w^n] (1+w)^{n+1} 
\left(-1 + \frac{(1+2w)^{n+1}}{(1+w)^{n+1}}\right)
\frac{1}{1+w-w^2}.$$

Adding the first and the second contribution we find

$$[w^n] (1+2w)^{n+1} \frac{1}{1+w-w^2}
\\ = \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n+1}}
(1+2w)^{n+1} \frac{1}{1+w-w^2}.$$

Setting $w/(1+2w)=v$ or $w=v/(1-2v)$ so that $dw = 1/(1-2v)^2 \; dv$
we obtain

$$\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{v^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{1+v/(1-2v)-v^2/(1-2v)^2} \frac{1}{(1-2v)^2}
\\ = \underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{v^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-2v)^2+v(1-2v)-v^2}
\\ = \underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{v^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{1-3v+v^2}.$$

We have our answer:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
[v^n] \frac{1}{1-3v+v^2} = F_{2n+2}.}$$

It  remains  to  prove  that the  coefficient  extractor  returns  the
Fibonacci number as  claimed. The OGF of  even-index Fibonacci numbers
is

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} F_{2n} z^{2n} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{z}{1-z-z^2}
+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{(-z)}{1+z-z^2}
= \frac{z^2}{1-3z^2+z^4}.$$

This implies that

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} F_{2n} z^{n} = \frac{z}{1-3z+z^2}.$$

Therefore

$$F_{2n+2} = [z^{n+1}] \frac{z}{1-3z+z^2}
= [z^n] \frac{1}{1-3z+z^2}$$

as required.

Answer (score 0):

We shall use tessellations of a $1 \times n$ grid with (singleton) squares and dominoes to give a combinatorial proof. But first a quick lemma.

Lemma: A $1 \times m$ grid can be tessallated with $j$ dominoes and $m-2j$ squares in $\binom{m-j}{j}$ ways. ($m \geq j$)

Proof: We will show this using a one-one correspondence. Let $ \{a_1,\cdots,a_j \} $ be a $j-$set of  $[m-j]$ (of which there are clearly $\binom{m-j}{j}$. Now place dominoes at $ a_1,a_2+1, \cdots ,a_j+j-1$ and fill the rest of the grid with squares. It is easily shown that these configurations and sets are bijective.

Now to prove the stated formula, first observe that $F_{2n+1}$ is the number of tessellations of a $1 \times (2n+1)$ grid with  squares and dominoes.

Alternatively, such a configuration will have $k$ dominoes and $2n-2k+1$ squares. Observe that there will always be an odd number of squares and we consider the position of the "middle" square. There will be $j$ dominoes to the left of this square and $i$ squares to the right. ($i+j=k$).

To the left there are $j$ dominoes and $n-k$ squares, by the lemma there are $\binom{n-i}{j}$ ways to arrange these and similarly to the right there are $i$ dominoes and $n-k$ squares, by the lemma there are $\binom{n-j}{i}$ ways to arrange these.

So
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{2n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-i} \binom{n-i}{j} \binom{n-j}{i}.
\end{eqnarray*}
In a nut shell this formula gives the number of tessellations of a $1 \times (2n+1)$ grid graded by the number of dominoes to the left and right of the central square.